# Openapi 3 generation of test´s

Tags: devops

I can gerate a dotnet 6 api project.

like so

```
dotnew new "webapi"
```

I can run it directly with dotnet.

like so

```
dotnet run
```

I can directly generate a client from the given swagger.json.

like so

```
docker run --rm \
  -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
  -i /local/swagger.json \
  -g csharp-netcore \
  -o /local/out/csharp-netcore
```

And I can also even build the client dll

like so

```
dotnet build
```

What I ask my self, currently. Is there also a way, to automatically generate a test project, for any operation in the API?

Answer (score 1):

The best answear I found my self currently is.

```
    docker run --rm \
  -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
  -i /local/swagger.json \
  -g k6 \
  -o /local/out/k6
```

https://k6.io/docs/test-types/introduction/